# Jquery error/conflict in SobiPro and MegaMenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla2.5, conflict, sobipro

The mega menu doesn't work on SobiPro pages on my Joomla 2.5 install. I have been trying to find if there is a conflict but no luck so far. Firebug throws up the following error which i have tried to amend but again no luck:

```
TypeError: $(...).megamenu is not a function
'justify': 'left'
```

This relates the following area of javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
    $('#meganavigator').megamenu({
        'wrap':'#yt_menuwrap .container',
        'easing': 'jswing',
        'speed': '500',
        'justify': 'left'
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Should I surround `.megamenu` like this: `$('.megamenu')`?

How do I go about finding the conflict (if there is one) and rectifying it?

Any help is greatly appreaciated. The menu works fine on standard conntet pages etc. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a link? Without that it's hard to say for sure. My guess would be that both Sobipro and MegaMenu are loading different versions of jQuery which is causing a conflict. Before I spent too much time messing with this, I would install jQuery easy. This will clean up all of the instances of jQuery being loaded and put everything in to no conflict mode. The default parameters are generally enough to solve most problems but you might need to mess with it a little.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/jquery-scripts/18327

Comment: Hi Brent, thanks for getting back to me. The test link for the sobipro page is here: http://www.billericayessex.co.uk/jupgrade/directory/activities the menu doesn't work, but navigate to the home page or another content page and it's fine. 
I have installed the jquery easy plugin but have tried a few settings and no luck so far. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's definitely a jQuery conflict. Javascript console shows this - Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'megamenu'. Looking at the source, Sobi is loading this file - http://www.billericayessex.co.uk/jupgrade/components/com_sobipro/var/js/7e1ab019123b9037a0c2944d660fe108.js. Inside that file it is loading jQuery 1.7.2. jQuery Easy didn't catch it because of the filename. I believe you can turn of Javascript compression in SobiPro so that it loads jQuery as it's own file and that will allow jQuery Easy to work.

Comment: You're completely right Brent. Turned off the java compression in SobiPro and the menu works fine now.
Thank you for your help and knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by deleting the following line on components/com_sobipro/lib/js/jqnc.js:

SobiPro.setJq( jQuery.noConflict() );